# Xamarin form validation and ASP.Net WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Form app, and I am consuming an ASP.Net Web WebAPI with Model State for validation in my internal models. If I got a "bad request" my API return this JSON object:

```
{
    message: 'The request is invalid.',
    modelState: {
        model.**Name**: [
            "The name is empty"
        ]
    }
  }
```

So, I want to simplify my work in the UI to read that result, my question are: How can I do to use this object for display the error in my UI? or Does Xamarin Form have any helper like to ASP.NET MVC Validator **@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)**, it could display automatic the error in the UI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create behaviors for controls like the below one

```
public class EmailValidatorBehavior : Behavior<Entry>  
    {  
        const string emailRegex = @"^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" +  
            @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$";  


        protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry bindable)  
        {  
            bindable.TextChanged += HandleTextChanged;  
            base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);  
        }  

        void HandleTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)  
        {  
            bool IsValid = false;  
            IsValid = (Regex.IsMatch(e.NewTextValue, emailRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)));  
            ((Entry)sender).TextColor = IsValid ? Color.Default : Color.Red;  
        }  

        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry bindable)  
        {  
            bindable.TextChanged -= HandleTextChanged;  
            base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);  
        }  
    }
```

Use this behavior in XAML as below

Add namespace for your behavior

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Mynamespace.Behaviors"
```

Add behavior to the entry

```
<Entry x:Name="txtEmail"  Placeholder="Enter Your Password" >  
      <Entry.Behaviors>  
        <local:EmailValidatorBehavior />  
      </Entry.Behaviors>  
    </Entry>
```

The above behavior will validate email and change the textbox color ro red if the email is not valid. Like that you can create more behaviours

Comment: Can you get me more information about this? What about of XAML?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! but I mean, I have a PLC with all model, for every model's property I have a data notations for validations in my web api. How can I do to use those validations in Xamarin Form with that validation in every model [see this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141(v=vs.98).aspx)?